# qt to sql server connection

Tags: sql-server, qt, sql-server-2014

I have written this part of the code below in order to connect to SQL server in Qt:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

QString serverName = "LOCALHOST\\DESKTOP-24DRHDN";
QString dbName = "ADBProject";

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setConnectOptions();

QString dsn = QString("DRIVER={SQL Native Client};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;Trusted_Connection=Yes;").arg(serverName).arg(dbName);
db.setDatabaseName(dsn);

if(db.open()){
    qDebug() << "opened";
    db.close();
 }else{
    qDebug() << "error : " + db.lastError().text();
}
return a.exec();
```

}

but after execution, the below error appears. I'm new to qt hence,  I don't know what the problem is?

> "error : [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data Source name not found and no default driver specified QODBC : Unable to connect"

Comment: did you try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: yes, same error appeared

Comment: maybe this document can help: https://wiki.qt.io/ODBC ? What documentation did you use?

Comment: What is the "SQL Native Client"?  I thought for driver, you had to tell it the specific driver name (QODBC in this case).  Yes it seems redundant, but it is what I do, as opposed to pointing to an SQL source.  Also you can add db.setConnectionOptions("SQL_ATTR_TRACE=SQL_OPT_TRACE_ON") which might give you some better output.   Also, Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

For my case, if you connect the db on your own pc and login with windows authentication, you need to add `Trusted_Connection=Yes;`

```
const QString connectionTrustedTemplate = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
```